# Using fopen_s in C

Tags: c, visual-c++, fopen

I have a problem with programming in C, especially with fopen in Visual Studio. I read about the `fopen_s` function and added the following line to my project, but it still doesn't work.

```
_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

So I tried using `fopen_s` in this way:

```
FILE *fp;
errno_t err;
if ((err = fopen_s(&fp, "C:/File.txt", "rt")) != 0)
    printf("File was not opened\n");
else
    fprintf(fp, "Date: %s, Time: %s, Score: %i \n", __DATE__, __TIME__, score);
fclose(fp);
```

It's still crashing. What's wrong?

Comment: When does it crashes ? What does Visual say ?

Comment: What is "rt" supposed to stand for [might be the error]? This seems to be MSDN/CRT related. Try to find out which error you get by examining your error number (not only compare if it is not zero). As it seems a function called strerror_s is provided for this purpose. Can you have a try?

Comment: "it's still doesn't work." is nebulous at-best. Fails to open the file? Fails to detect a failure to open the file? Opens the file but crashes on close? Fails to open the file, reports error, then crashes on close (I'm hedging bets on this one with hyde)? Can you be at least a *little* more specific?

Comment: Okay, sorry. It's: "Unhandled exception at 0x00BE347E in Janusze Kosmosu.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Comment: when the fopen_s() fails, you should output appropriate message and exit program, not continue to the next statement.  BTW: the variable 'score' is being used, but not set anywhere AND why bother opening the file for read when you never read from it?

Comment: As a safeguard, the FILE *fp; should be FILE *fp = NULL;  then the incorrect call to fclose( fp ) would be passing NULL rather than being yet another reason for the program to crash at run time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use `fclose` with an invalid `fp` value, even if opening failed. Add `{}` around the `else` branch, at least.

Many developers think it is generally a good idea to use braces everywhere, even with one statement inside them. It's so easy to make a mistake like this if you don't, even for experienced developers. So put them around the *then* branch too.

Comment: _then_ branch?  Did you mean _else_? (second paragraph)

Comment: @ryyker Else branch needs them, I suggest putting them around then branch *too*.

Answer (score 6):

The `_s` functions are unportable Microsoft inventions which, for the most part, duplicate functionality that already existed under a more portable name.  Moreover, blindly changing from the non-`_s` variant of a function to the `_s` variant generally does *not* fix anything.  (For instance, silently truncating a string is *less disastrous* than clobbering the stack but it is still misbehavior which may be exploitable.)

Your problem -- which is not affected by the difference between `fopen` and `fopen_s` -- is almost certainly that you are not bothering to check for errors properly.  Here is how to check for errors *properly:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "opening %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno)); // HERE
        return 1;
    }

    // use 'fp' here...

    return 0;
}
```

Notice how the line marked `// HERE` prints *both* the exact string that was passed to `fopen` and the result of `strerror(errno)`.  It is absolutely essential that you print both the arguments and `strerror(errno)` whenever a system call fails.  (Note: If you do wind up using one of the `_s` functions that returns an error code rather than setting `errno`, then you must pass the return value to `strerror` instead.)

Change your program to do this and you will be able to figure out *why* it isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

//give it a shot, it's working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int score = 10;
    FILE *fp;
    errno_t err;
    if ((err = fopen_s(&fp, "C:\\Users\\achea\\Desktop\\File.txt", "w+")) != 0)
    {
        printf("File was not opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(fp, "Date: %s, Time: %s, Score: %i \n", __DATE__, __TIME__, 
        score);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows the slashes are different than on Linux, so you may consider using C:\File.txt instead of C:/File.txt.

Answer (score -3):

Regarding the mode you are using to open,

```
 err = fopen_s(&fp, "C:/File.txt", "rt")
```

I never used the letter t as a parameter and don't know what that is for...

But you are opening with R (read) and trying to write...

Try

```
 err = fopen_s(&fp, "C:/File.txt", "w")
```

or

```
 err = fopen_s(&fp, "C:/File.txt", "w+")
```

Also, you don't really need the err variable. If the fopen call fails, the pointer will be NULL.

Comment: -1 for telling people not to record detailed error codes.  BTW, "t" is for "text" and is opposed to "b" for "binary."  It's not necessary (it's the default) but in some contexts it can make expectations clearer.

Comment: -1 for solving his problem? Or -1 to make the code more portable? Tell me where he is getting this error code if he try to use it outside visual studio? As far as I remember the signature is: "FILE * fopen ( const char * filename, const char * mode );" And I don't see him using this error code for anything that couldn't be done be checking the pointer. -10 for ... i better not tell

Comment: It was -1 specifically for "you don't really need the err variable." You can know that the `fopen(_s)` failed by checking whether the pointer is `NULL`, but you need the `err` variable to know *why* the operation failed. The OP's program neglects to inspect `err`, which is a *bug*. You should not be encouraging them to make it worse; instead (as outlined in my answer) you should have explained the use of `strerror` and/or `perror` to turn an error code into a human-readable diagnostic message.